# .htaccess let subdomain behave as main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to create subdomain just for one page of main domain. I don't want to have copy of files so i try to solve it using mod_rewrite.

Simply when i go to submdomain.domain.com i want to show page xyz.html as index.html with all pictures. The mod rewrite should keep address in browser url as subdomain.domain.com

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [P,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.html
RewriteRule index.html http://www.domain.com/xyz.html [P,L]
```

this .htaccess is saved in subdomain of root directory. Unfortunately it works only separatly. First half works only when second half is missing and vice versa. So i am able to do redirect to show only xyz.html page as index page but without images, or do redirect for all subdomain files but xyz.html is ignored and main domain index.html is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end i have found the solution

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.html
RewriteRule index.html http://www.domain.com/myspecial-page.html [P,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+).html$ http://www.domain.com/$1.html [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^images/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+)$ http://www.domain.com/images/$1 [NC,P]

etc...for css, js
```

it is possible to test rules using [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)